# How to vertically center content within Stack.Screen including header into calculation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to vertically center content within [`Stack.Screen`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/native-stack-navigator.html) including header into calculation?

Currently, if I try to vertically center element on the screen it will be slightly shifted to the bottom of the screen due to `Stack.Screen` header. I would like to take this size into calculation without using `margin-top: -N` where `N` is the size of the header.

Why without margin? Because it adds additional complexity of handling the iOS and Android devices.

navigator.component.tsx

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    name='SignIn'
    component={SignInComponent}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

sign-in.component.tsx

```
const SignInComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Example</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

[image: React-navigation screenshot #1]
[image: React-navigation screenshot #2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why without margin? Because it adds additional complexity of handling the iOS and Android devices.

What complexity does it add?

```js
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// ...

const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();

<View style={{ height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: -headerHeight }}>
  <Text>Example</Text>
</View>
```